# Oracle forms hangs on Java 1.6 and works with Java 1.8

Tags: java, oracle, oracleforms

have noticed a strange situation. We use oracle forms "server" and the front end is a Java Applet. Now some of the users have Java 1.6.0_45 installed and others have Java 1.8.0. On a form we also use a PJC component (Java pluggable component) which is made - compiled with JDK 1.6.0_25 version of Java.

The exception when someone runs a form with Java 1.6.0_45 is:
[image]

and fine when the same form runs on Java 1.8:
[image]

The problem with Java 1.6.0 is that it fails before the constructor of PJC is even been called.

What could it be wrong? 
The first exception in Java console is:
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.lang.RuntimePermission accessClassInPackage.sun.java2d)

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a certain java version all jars must be signed with the same official signature. If you didn't do that java will not allow to run the jars.